# Why doesn't this data model filter as expected? Trying filter a table through a series of one to many relationships

Tags: excel, one-to-many, powerpivot, erd

Please see the ERD below. I have a data model that I built in Excel Power Pivot that resembles the model below (simplified for explanation purposes).

What I'm trying to do is filter the Tech Hours table via the Branch Mapping table. Let's assume I filter the Region column in the Branch Mapping table to USA. Because this table has a one to many relationship with the Tech Mapping table, this will then filter the Tech Mapping table to only the records in the USA Region.

However, this filter is not passed along to the Tech Hours table. When I apply this filter to the Branch Mapping table, none of the data in Tech Hours is filtered.

Why not? If it filters the Tech Mapping table to BranchIDs in the US (and thus only Tech IDs in the US), shouldn't that in turn do the same to my Tech Hours table since it also has a one to many relationship?

[Picture of my ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzJiq.png)

Comment: can you post DAX code that you are trying to filter?

Comment: There is no dax code involved, I am just trying to filter a pivot table with fields from the data model.

Comment: Your data model should work. There must be something else that you have not described in your question. if you can, provide a powerpivot mock up file that demonstrates the problem, I'll look at it.